# Strength of anti-debugging technique

Tags: c, linux, debugging, process, ptrace

Having used to debug with tools like gdb etc, I have little knowledge about they get implemented. I am trying to implement an anti debugging technique in my program but having very little knowledge about debugging, I need some help. I have come across following code from http://www.julioauto.com/rants/anti_ptrace.htm

```
void anti_ptrace(void)
{
    pid_t child;

    if(getenv("LD_PRELOAD"))
        while(1);

    child = fork();
    if (child)
        wait(NULL);
    else 
    {
        pid_t parent = getppid();

        if (ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, parent, 0, 0) < 0)
            while(1);

        sleep(1);
        ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, parent, 0, 0);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

I want to have expert opinion of you gurus about how successful the above code will be and what are Pros and cons?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to anti-debug? why?

Comment: Actually I am building a library and I dont want that some other process can ptrace it. Its a sort of compulsion.

Comment: And will keep me from simply taking your binary and patching it to skip these things?

Comment: You're wasting your time.

Comment: this kind of "protection" is 
a) VERY easy detectable 
b) VERY easy overridden
c) can be removed VERY easy from compiled binaries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way you can actually protect your algorithms from debugging or decompiling is to restrict access to their binaries - by running them on remote machine and accessing via TCP/IP. **Any** *local* solution will eventually fail in hands of determined cracker.